# error deploying to heroku "No input file specified"

Tags: php, node.js, html, git, heroku

i have a project on github that is a simple HTML web page personal portfolio. I attempted to deploy to Heroku from the CLI and it seems that the site deployed correctly as far as i can tell. there are no errors in heroku dashboard, but when i launch the app the browser states "No input file specified." the site works locally and it works on godaddy servers with no errors. I have created an "index.php" and "composer.json" files as the documentation suggested but still getting the error and google hasnt been much help. 
has anyone else experienced this?
my kingdom for any assistance...

Comment: update: nothing shows in the log, but the app shows as build successful and deployed under the overview tab

Answer (score 0):

i found out what the problem was. in case anyone else runs into this there was a user.ini file from when i hosted on godaddy's plesk servers on the root of my project that was screwing everything up. i removed it, redeployed and it wrks fine now.